# Sagemaker Endpoint returning strange error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

Hey guys so recently i started working with sagemaker and I was testing autopilot and it got a fairly good accuracy and I wanted to test it on some more data so I chose the one with best ACC and created an endpoint. The problem now is that I don't know how to use the endpoit properly. I tried using AWS CLI but I keep getting the following errors:

The command:

```
aws sagemaker-runtime invoke-endpoint --endpoint-name autopilottest --body 'SW0gaGFwcHk=' f
```

The error message:

```
An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (415) from container-1 with message "'application/json' is an unsupported content type.". See https://eu-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=eu-west-2#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/autopilottest in account 288240193481 for more information.
```

The command:

```
aws sagemaker-runtime invoke-endpoint --endpoint-name autopilottest --body 'Im happy!' f
```

The error message:

```
Invalid base64: "Im happy!"
```

Endpoit configuration:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up fixing the issue by adding `--content-type text/csv` and using base64 and it worked like a charm.

Comment: can you add a complete command here